# Style dynamic created tabitems

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a list of objects binded to my tabcontrol. Now I can create dynamic tabitems. Here is the WPF code:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding FileCollection}" Grid.Row="1">
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
  <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Now I want to give the tabitem a style. How can I apply it to the tabitem?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
  ...
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by using `TabControl`'s `Resources` property:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding FileCollection}" Grid.Row="1">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="..." Value="..." />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! This isn't working perfectly. I have created a `TabItem ControlTemplate`. How can I use this? `<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    ...
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>`

Comment: After hours of searching the mistake I found it... They style had an `x:Key`. Thanks for your help!